# Question about filtration of sigma algebra?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $F_n$ is a filtration, which means $F_n \subset F_{n+1}$.

Then if $Z_1$ is $F_0$ measurable, then is it true that it is $F_m$($m\ge 2$) measurable?

Thanks so much! Your help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Z_1$ is $F_0$-measurable means the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $Z_1$ is contained in $F_0$. As $F_0\subset F_m$ for all $m\geq 0$, $Z_1$ is $F_m$-measurable for all such $m$.